# Package or namespace load failed for sparklyr

Tags: r, sparklyr

The latest version of sparklyr from CRAN seems to install, but can't load:

> library(sparklyr)
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sparklyr’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
> number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
>
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘sparklyr’ was built under R version 3.5.3

I've tried re-installing dplyr and lazyeval and restarting the R session from inside RStudio.  Any thoughts?

Here's my sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1        magrittr_1.5      usethis_1.5.0     devtools_2.0.2    pkgload_1.0.2     R6_2.4.0          rlang_0.3.4       httr_1.4.0        tools_3.5.1       pkgbuild_1.0.3    sessioninfo_1.1.1
[12] cli_1.1.0         DBI_1.0.0         withr_2.1.2       htmltools_0.3.6   remotes_2.0.4     yaml_2.2.0        assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.18     rprojroot_1.3-2   forge_0.2.0       crayon_1.3.4     
[23] processx_3.3.0    callr_3.2.0       fs_1.3.1          base64enc_0.1-3   ps_1.3.0          testthat_2.1.1    glue_1.3.1        memoise_1.1.0     compiler_3.5.1    desc_1.2.0        backports_1.1.4  
[34] prettyunits_1.0.2
```

Comment: What is your R Version?

Comment: R version 3.5.1 - sorry that didn't didn't print under sessionInfo()

Comment: Any reason you can't upgrade R? That version is from last July

Comment: Not without waiting a week for IT to package it.  Arghhhhh!

Comment: I can install it and load it with a R version 3.4.3